# How to transfer photo sent as SMS to Photos/iPhoto.app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, import

Somebody sent me six images with SMS to my iPhone. I want to email these and get them on my Mac to use there. Short of copying them one by one into an email on my iPhone is there any way I can transfer these into Photos so that iPhoto will import them to my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visit the conversation in your iPhone/iPad in Messages, click on the 'Details' button in the upper right hand corner, scroll down to attachments, then press and hold one of the photos you'd like to transfer. Select "More" from the menu that appears.

You should then see Apple's 'Select' arrows appear in the bottom of each attachment. From there, select your photos, and share them however you'd like (email all 6 or save them to your photo app).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

- Tip on each foto and save it to your Pictures Gallery.
- Open the Photos App, select them and send them by email.
- Delete the photos afterwards.